# Not able to read xlsx file even after installing 'openpyxl'

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I want to read both .xls and .xlsx file to a dataframe, according to what is written on the internet, the packages ['xlrd' and 'openpyxl'] should be installed in my system

my system is MAC with both [python and Jupyter lab] installed independently, and [Anaconda] is installed too, and I can run the Jupyter Lan either from the Terminal or from the Anaconda browser.

after installing the 'xlrd' i can read the .xls files without problems.

but after installing the 'openpyxl' and attempt to-read .xlsx file, the following error rises:

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the openpyxl but still, the same problem exists.

meantime I checked both installations of the openpyxl, in Anaconda it is v3.0.5, and in python
it is v3.0.6

is this normal??

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f15b3a520ce0> in <module>
      1 ### 1.2 : Load Sciamgo Jurnal Excel file with xlsx format
----> 2 xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('assets/scimagojr-3.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
      3 sciamgo = pd.read_excel(xlsx)
      4 
      5 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in __init__(self, io, engine)
    822         self._io = stringify_path(io)
    823 
--> 824         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
    825 
    826     def __fspath__(self):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    482             Object to be parsed.
    483         """
--> 484         import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
    485         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
    486 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py in import_optional_dependency(name, extra, raise_on_missing, on_version)
     90     except ImportError:
     91         if raise_on_missing:
---> 92             raise ImportError(msg) from None
     93         else:
     94             return None

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```